# Is gurgle available on homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, gnu

I don't find gurgle on homebrew. Is it available somewhere?

https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Gurgle

Comment: You can try searching yourself with `brew search gurgle`. I didn't find it.

Comment: I didn’t find it. But it seems to be a decent project. I am surprised it is not on brew. So I want to confirm.